# How to query a Maximo domain with SQL?

Tags: sql, select, oracle12c, lookup-tables, maximo

I have a domain in Maximo 7.6.1.1 called DIVISIONS.

---

[image]

---

I would like to write a SELECT statement that queries the DIVISIONS domain to get the VALUE and DESCRIPTION fields.

*The query would be made into a view; to be used in a separate database via a dblink.*

**How can I query a Maximo domain with SQL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can query the ALNDOMAIN table (ALN stands for alphanumeric):

```
select
    *
from
    alndomain
where
    domainid = 'DIVISIONS'
```

[image]

---

For what it's worth, there is also a *parent* domain table (for lack of a better word).

```
select
    *
from
    maxdomain
where
    domainid = 'DIVISIONS'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just to add the MAXDOMAIN table identifies the domain description and type (DOMAINTYPE).

For Table Domains and Crossover Domains (both look up values from a database table, there will be an additional entry in the MAXTABLEDOMAIN. The OBJECTNAME attribute on this record will identify the source table being referenced.

For Crossover Domains, the CROSSOVERDOMAIN table will contain a number of Source and Destination pairs for the target Domain - and when used will cause the source values to be copied from the table identified as OBJECTNAME to the target table which is associated with the Crossover Domain.

You can see whats domains are linked to individual attributes by looking at the MAXATTRIBUTE table (WHERE ATTRIBUTENAME = 'target attribute' AND OBJECTNAME = 'target_object' and then inspecting the DOMAINID value)

:)

Answer (score 0):

In maximo, there's a table which contains entries for all types of domain.
In order to query that table you can query like

```
SELECT * FROM MAXDOMAIN WHERE DOMAINID='DOMAINID' AND DOMAINTYPE='SYNONYM';
```

maximo has seperate tables based upon the type of domains.

```
SELECT * FROM NUMRANGEDOMAIN WHERE DOMAINID='NUMRANGEDOMAINID';

SELECT * FROM CROSSOVERDOMAIN WHERE DOMAINID='CROSSOVERDOMAINID';

SELECT * FROM ALNDOMAIN WHERE DOMAINID='ALNDOMAINID';

SELECT * FROM SYNONYMDOMAIN WHERE DOMAINID='SYNONYMDOMAINID';
```

Comment: PS: There's no seperate table for table domain and domainId is nothing ut name of your domain

Comment: Yes there is - MAXTABLEDOMAIN (contains crossover domains and table domain definitions, see CROSSOVERDOMAIN for additional field level details)